# ReactJs Element type is invalid Check the render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs

I've been trying to solve the error when using tabs in my ReactJS application.
So I've created a brand-new app with the command:

```
 create-react-app my-app
```

and added the following to the App.js render() function as per react-bootstrap docs:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={2} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
  <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
    Tab 1 content
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
    Tab 2 content
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>
    Tab 3 content
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

This is the resulting code:

```
import React, { Component, Tabs, Tab } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey={2} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
              Tab 1 content
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
              Tab 2 content
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>
              Tab 3 content
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

The App.js file is imported in index.js. Same folder (src folder). 
This is the file content:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I still get the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render
>   method of `App`.

I'd say there is no problem with the export as the app works well without the Tabs snippet of code. 
Apparently, using tabs causes this problem, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the above.

I will appreciate your help.
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add to your post the code where you mount the `<App />` component, as well as the directories/hierarchy of your project?

Comment: I've added where I mount <App />.
Importing Tabs and Tab solved the error but there is no css applied.

Answer (score 4):

The error shows up because the module `'react'` doesn't actually export any component named `Tabs` or `Tab`, so when you try to import them from there, you'll get `undefined`.

If the component comes from `'react-bootstrap'`, import it from there, not from `'react'`. [See the Getting Started docs for an example.](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#es6)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
```

Comment: OK, fair enough. Now I get in which cases I can get that sort of errors. Thanks. Now, the original problem was with a slightly more complex bit of code, when using mdb and importing a complext Tabs structure.
import { Container, Row, Col, TabPane, TabContent, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'mdbreact';

The above is imported from mdb react, but using those components in my tabs, gives the same error.

Comment: It turns out that the above is only present in the PRO version, so the error is always been thrown when a Component is not found in a particular library. I find the description of the error a bit misleading.